# How to know if my Windows 7 installation has a separate boot partition?

Tags: windows-7, boot

When i open disk management, i can only find C: partition. But, when i start Windows in repair mode, i can see a small size partition with letter X: named boot. So what's the right method to tell if all Windows 7 components reside on the same partition?

Comment: Is there a "Boot" folder on C:? If so this is what repair mode uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disk Management is the correct method. If nothing is there, you do not have a separate boot partition. Hidden partitions are a thing of the past.

You can also check on the Windows partition, using Explorer (but the files/folders may be hidden). The Windows partition will contain a folder *Boot* which contains, among others, a file *BCD* (without extension). This is however not definite proof, because the files could be there but unused.

When booting in Startup Repair (or Recovery in general, also Windows Setup), what you have at *X:* is the recovery system itself. It’s a virtual drive that is created from a WIM image file.